# Django REST Framework: How to combine two querysets?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-filter

I'm trying to combine two filters which are referred to a FK in an object but I'm getting wrong and redundant data.

Below presented the filters, located in views.py:

```
class RecordFilter(df.FilterSet):
    user = df.CharFilter(name='active_states__user', method='filter_user')
    activestate = df.BooleanFilter(name='active_states__is_active', method='filter_is_active')

    class Meta:
        model = Record
        fields = ['type', 'group', 'user', 'activestate']

    def filter_user(self, queryset, _, value):
        return queryset.filter(active_states__user_id=value)

    def filter_is_active(self, queryset, _, value):
        return queryset.filter(active_states__is_active=value)
```

For example in my test case I created 4 record objects and I added to them activestate and user.

```
record1.set_active_states_for_users([user1.uuid], True)
record2.set_active_states_for_users([user1.uuid], False)
record2.set_active_states_for_users([user2.uuid], True)
record3.set_active_states_for_users([user2.uuid], False)
```

I tried to test these filters for user=user2 and activestate=True.
And I'm getting:

- Two times the record2 because of activestate=True and user=user2
- One time the record3 because of user=user2

The result should be only the record2.

I noticed that the `chain` could do the concatenation of the querysets, but I don't know how can I use it in my views.py in class RecordFilter. Do you have any clue?

Comment: Why should result be record2 if `record2.set_active_states_for_users([user1.uuid], False)` and you filter `activestate=True`?

Comment: And why do you do `queryset.filter(active_states__user_id=value)` if `user = df.CharFilter`? In your case you don't need `method` args at all. You filter logic is duplicated in field definition and method. `name` arg works like filter statement.

Comment: The result should be only the record2 because is the only record which covers both filters by (3rd line) `record2.set_active_states_for_users([user2.uuid], True)`. 
Also, in your second comment you mean that when you have filed definition and method, maybe you will get duplicates?

Answer (score 3):

You have situation described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships). It is possible to implement this API:

```
class RecordFilter(df.FilterSet):
    active_user = df.CharFilter(method='filter_active_user')
    disabled_user = df.CharFilter(method='filter_disabled_user')

    class Meta:
        model = Record
        fields = ['type', 'group', 'user']

def filter_active_user(self, queryset, name, value):
    return queryset.filter(active_states__is_active=True,
                           active_states__user_id=value)

def filter_disabled_user(self, queryset, name, value):
    return queryset.filter(active_states__is_active=False,
                           active_states__user_id=value)
```

So you can filter both any, only disabled and only enabled users.
Query active_user=user2 will return just record2.

But I don't know why do you use `CharFilter` for `user` and filter queryset like `active_states__user_id=value`. Looks like mistake if `id` is not a string.

Comment: I'm using ChalrFilter because the id of user is a String.

Your solution is partially correct for the above problem, but in case that I want to add more filters like on type or on group, I will have the same problem and I will have to create many other variables like `filter_active_user_group` or `filter_disabled_user_group` to avoid the wrong results. 
So I think that I need a general solution for how to combine these querysets.